# Analyticity of the initial data

Tags: general-relativity, computational-physics

Consider an initial data $(q_{i j},K_{i j})$ on a Cauchy hypersurface $\Sigma$ in a globally hyperbolic spacetime. How reasonable is it to impose the condition that these functions are analytic? I am especially thinking of realistic scenarios tha arise in numerical relativity. An example of a useful case where it fails is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about the existence of analytic initial data? I'm having trouble with the part of the question that says "impose the condition that these functions are analytic" because you started the question by assuming that you already had the data.

Comment: I see. Well, the initial data is not given. I am just looking at what possible mathematical conditions does a generic initial data obey. I'm not looking at existence; I know examples where it is smooth analytic. I can also intuitively see how it can fail to be at a mathematical level (bump function metric). Question is, as a physicist, what realistic situation would you encounter where the initial data turns out to be smooth but not analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial data must obey the Hamiltonian constraint and the momentum constraint.  Those are second order differential equations on the 3-metric and its conjugate momentum. (Or other related quantities, depending on which flavor of the 3+1 decomposition you use.) Other than that, it can be anything, and I would think there's enough freedom there to construct something mathematically perverse if you wanted to do so.

Black hole initial data for numerical relativity, looking at it more from a physics perspective, for all but the simplest scenarios, is usually computed numerically by solving the constraint equations.  You may not have many guarantees or even insight into its mathematical properties beyond that, although such a statement would depend in part on how the problem was set up, the solution method, etc.  Here's a reference to one of the older papers on initial data for multiple black holes.  You could work forward from there: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9703066